# How do I troubleshoot "no medium found" error on installation on Mac?

Tags: installation, 12.10, mac

Specifically, it says

```
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: no medium found
```

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my intel iMac. I have 1 Mac partition, 1 FAT32 partition with Windows installed on it, and 2 MS-DOS(FAT) partitions which have nothing on them yet, if that helps. I am using rEFIt

Comment: If you boot with a live CD, can you see the partitions with fdisk -l?

Comment: I mistyped, 12.10. Thanks for catching my error

Comment: @Ken how do I go about running commands when the UI won't load. The furthest I have gotten is a dark grey bar at the top (no buttons on it) and a pretty purple background when trying to boot from CD. I should note that I do in fact see these things on my display's native resolution, rather than whatever low res the boot menu shows up in (idk if thats relevant, maybe it will help)

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant this happened during the install itself, not when it was just booting off the CD.

Comment: You might try a couple of other distros' live CDs to make sure it's a Linux issue, not one specific to Ubuntu. Also if there's a Mac program that can give you an output like fdisk -l, that would be helpful, but I'm not sure what that Mac app would be.

Answer (score 1):

So I haven't found the cause of the problem, but I've discovered that if I boot from a CD, but also insert a bootable usb drive, then just ignore it, the live cd will eventually load the normal interface.